# Rider copying and pasting text from word pastes as image link

Tags: ide, rider

I'm writing a small website in markdown (.md file) which is then processed by jekyll, using rider as the IDE.

Because Rider's spellcheck isn't great, I'm writing in Word and copy-pasting into the markdown file.

Whenever I copy and paste, for some reason the defualt behaviour is to try paste my text as an image...

Trying to paste "*Lorem Ipsum*" with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> pastes "`![img.png](img.png)`", linking to some corrupt image presumably trying to hold the text i've written.

While is is possible to paste as raw text with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, this is really annoying, is there any way to change this default behaviour to not try paste text as an image?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this issue and it really seems like a bug to me. It would be cool if you could file an issue [here](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=97145) so that the IDE becomes better and better.

Comment: Is there an issue now?